# Pass Wx Frame class as a variable to another Class

Tags: python, class, wxpython, wxwidgets, python-class

I am trying to pass a WX frame class to another class. I have three py files which are as follows:

**gui_20220510.py** - this contains the gui code

```
import wx

class Frame_Demo(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: Frame_Demo.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))

        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.notebook_1 = wx.Notebook(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer_1.Add(self.notebook_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.notebook_1_pane_1 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.notebook_1_pane_1, "notebook_1_pane_1")

        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self.notebook_1_pane_1, wx.ID_ANY, "This is Test: ")
        sizer_2.Add(label_1, 0, 0, 0)

        self.text_ctrl_1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.notebook_1_pane_1, wx.ID_ANY, "Type")
        sizer_2.Add(self.text_ctrl_1, 0, 0, 0)

        self.notebook_1_pane_2 = wx.Panel(self.notebook_1, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.notebook_1_pane_2, "notebook_1_pane_2")

        sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        sizer_3.Add((0, 0), 0, 0, 0)

        self.notebook_1_pane_2.SetSizer(sizer_3)

        self.notebook_1_pane_1.SetSizer(sizer_2)

        self.panel_1.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.Layout()
```

**demo.py** - This contains the run functions to import the wx frame

```
from importlib import import_module
from wx import App

global Frame_Demo
global builddate

class Demo_Main(Frame_Demo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        Frame_Demo.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        # Update the Frame Title to Reflect Build Date
        self.SetTitle('Demo Tool v' + builddate)
        self.Maximize(True)

def main_run(bdate, gui_version):
    global builddate
    global Frame_Demo
    builddate = bdate
    gui_module = import_module('gui_' + gui_version)
    Frame_Demo = gui_module.Frame_Demo
    app = App()
    frame = Demo_Main(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Main.py** - This is the main file to run the program

```
from demo import main_run

builddate = '2022-MAY-10'
gui_version = '20220510'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_run(builddate, gui_version)
```

When trying to run main.py, I am  getting "Frame_Demo" is not defined error even though it was defined as a global.

What am I doing wrong here? any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Word `global` is NOT for creating global variables. All variables created outside functions are automtically global (but you have to assign value to variable to create it)  We use `global` inside function to inform function that when we use `=` to assign new value then it has to use external/global variable instead of creating local one. But you should import `Frame_Demo` before you define `class Demo_Main(Frame_Demo):` . So you need `Frame_Demo = gui_module.Frame_Demo` before `class Demo_Main(Frame_Demo):` Or define this class inside `main_run`, after `Frame_Demo = gui_module.Frame_Demo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word `global` is NOT for creating global variables. All variables created outside functions are automtically global (inside current module) but you have to assign value to variable to create it.

We use `global` inside function to inform function that when we use `=` to assign new value to variable then it has to use external/global variable instead of creating local one.

So you have to import `Frame_Demo` before you define `class Demo_Main(Frame_Demo):`. Or you have to define this class inside `main_run`, after `Frame_Demo = gui_module.Frame_Demo`

```
from importlib import import_module
from wx import App

def main_run(builddate, gui_version):

    gui_module = import_module('gui_' + gui_version)
    Frame_Demo = gui_module.Frame_Demo

    class Demo_Main(Frame_Demo):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
            # Update the Frame Title to Reflect Build Date
            self.SetTitle('Demo Tool v' + builddate)
            self.Maximize(True)

    app = App()
    frame = Demo_Main(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could also put these value in separated file - ie. **settings.py**

```
builddate = '2022-MAY-10'
gui_version = '20220511'
```

and import it to **demo.py**

```
from importlib import import_module
from wx import App

import settings

gui_module = import_module('gui_' + settings.gui_version)
Frame_Demo = gui_module.Frame_Demo

class Demo_Main(Frame_Demo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
        # Update the Frame Title to Reflect Build Date
        self.SetTitle('Demo Tool v' + settings.builddate)
        self.Maximize(True)

def main_run():
    app = App()
    frame = Demo_Main(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And run **main.py** without these values

```
from demo import main_run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_run()
```